# Cannot load alternating urls with UIWebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have one view holding a list of videos(buttons which can be clicked, each hold a url) which currently bring up a new view which holds the UIWebview, the only problem is I cant pass the url to the webview depending on which button was clicked.

At the moment I just get an empty UIWebview.

How can the url string be passed to the webview so it can load the correct url for each button?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:videoURL]];
```

**UPDATE:**

In response to comment #3, here's what you can do:

1. This goes without saying, but keep a reference to the `UIWebView` instance in `Browser`
2. Add an NSString or NSURL `@property` to `Browser`
3. Pass the URL to the `Browser` instance right after init
4. In `viewDidLoad:`, call `loadRequest:`

So your code might look like this:

```
- (void)buttonClicked {
    Browser *browser = [[Browser alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    browser.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http..."];
    [self presentModalViewController:browser animated:YES];
    [browser release];
}
```

and in Browser's `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL]];
}
```

Comment: I have code to load a url, but m not sure where to put it? If I put each url request in each button for the url needed, I cannot tie that to the webview? I would like to put the code in the viewdidload method of the webview, but am not sure how to give it the correct url from the button pressed.

Comment: That depends on how you're loading the webview -- are you initializing it yourself? If so, extend the init function to include a new argument which is the URL.

Comment: I have the following code to show the view holding the webview
              Browser *b = [[Browser alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:b animated:YES];
 and I just have a UIWebview *browser in my Browser class which is link in IB. regards